# How are S-box calculated in S-AES?

Tags: encryption, aes, s-boxes

> Read the Reference for [Simplified AES](https://www.rose-hulman.edu/~holden/Preprints/s-aes.pdf) ( S-AES )
>
> [image]
>
> **Q1** Explain how the S- box is constructed  taking example $b_0b_1b_2b_3=1010$

**What I did**

$\begin{bmatrix} 
1 &0  &1  &1 \\ 
1 &  1&  0&1 \\ 
 1&  1& 1 & 0\\ 
0 &1  &  1& 1
\end{bmatrix}
*\begin{bmatrix}
b_0\\ 
b_1\\ 
b_2\\ 
b_3
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$

$= \begin{bmatrix} 
1 &0  &1  &1 \\ 
1 &  1&  0&1 \\ 
 1&  1& 1 & 0\\ 
0 &1  &  1& 1
\end{bmatrix}
*\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
1\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$

$= \begin{bmatrix}
(1011\times1) \bigoplus (1011\times0)\bigoplus (1011\times1)\bigoplus (1011\times0) \\ 
(1101\times1) \bigoplus (1101\times0)\bigoplus (1101\times1)\bigoplus (1101\times0)\\ 
(1110\times1) \bigoplus (1110\times0)\bigoplus (1110\times1)\bigoplus (1110\times0)\\ 
(0111\times1) \bigoplus (0111\times0)\bigoplus (0111\times1)\bigoplus (0111\times0)
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$

$=\begin{bmatrix}
1011 \bigoplus 0\bigoplus 1011\bigoplus 0 \\ 
1101 \bigoplus 0\bigoplus 1101\bigoplus 0\\ 
1110 \bigoplus 0\bigoplus 1110\bigoplus 0\\ 
0111 \bigoplus 0\bigoplus 0111\bigoplus 0
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$

$=
\begin{bmatrix}
1011 \bigoplus1011 \\ 
1101 \bigoplus1101\\ 
1110 \bigoplus 1110\\ 
0111\bigoplus 0111
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$

$=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}\bigoplus\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$

Im getting S-box transformation of $1010$ as $1001$ . Where am i doing wrong ?

> **Q2** Also Explain the meaning of the statement and its relevance in construction of S-Box 
>   " The addition and multiplication in the equation above are being done modulo 2 (with XOR), but not in GF(16)

Comment: Applying the matrix to  $1010$ yields the sum of the first and the third column, ergo: $0101$. But you forget the inverse !

Comment: Correct your matrix multiplication please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the inverse over the field first, then the affine transform on that.

You must first invert $1010 = x^3 + x$ in $\textrm{GF}(16)$, with prime polynomial $x^4 + x + 1$; use the extended Euclidean algorithm for that, and see that $1100 = x^3+x^2$ is the inverse (you can verify this by computing their product and replacing all $x^4$ by $1+x$ an ditto for higher powers $x^5 = x^2+x$, $x^6 = x^3+x^2$ etc.; we are left with $1$, using $x+x=0$ etc.)

You can also make a log table based on the generator $x$:

$$
\begin{matrix}
0 & x^0 & 1 & 0001\\
1 & x^1 & x & 0010\\
2 & x^2  & x^2 & 0100\\
3 & x^3 & x^3 & 1000\\
4 & x^4 & 1+x & 0011\\  
5 & x^5 & x^2+x & 0110\\
6 & x^6 & x^3 + x^2 & 1100\\
7 &  x^7 & x^3 + x + 1 & 1011\\
8 & x^8 & x^2 +1 & 0101\\
9 & x^9 & x^3+x & 1010\\
10 & x^{10} & x^2+x+1 & 0111\\
11 & x^{11} & x^3 + x^2 +x & 1110\\
12 & x^{12} & x^3 + x^2 +x + 1 & 1111\\
13 & x^{13} & x^3 + x^2 +1 & 1101\\
14 & x^{14} & x^3 + 1 & 1001\\
15 & x^{15} & 1 & 0001
\end{matrix} 
$$
And note that $1010 = x^9$ so its inverse is $x^6 = 1100$ (as $x^{15} = 1$).

We then apply the affine transform over $F_2$ to $1100$, we get for the matrix multiplication as the sum of the first two columns with result $\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}+ \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\1\\1 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$

and adding the constant vector $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}$ to that we get $0000$, as required.

As an aside: $0000$ has no inverse, so we use the convention  that its "inverse" is $0000$ and into the affine transform this yields the constant vector $1001$, as the table says. The point of the affine tarnsform is to ensure the $S$-box defined by the (very nonlinear) inverse mapping does not have $0000$ as a fix point. The element $0001$ has $0001$ as its inverse, and then the matrix multiplication gives $1101$ (the last column) and so adding $1001$ gives $0100$ etc.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66526/discussion-on-answer-by-henno-brandsma-how-are-s-box-calculated-in-s-aes).